# Запятые при обороте "как ни крути"

Tags: пунктуация

"Происходящее объясняется тем, что(,) как ни крути, а основной контингент читателей журнала - женщины".

Усомнилась в том, нужна ли запятая перед "как". Ведь если выбросить "как ни крути", то получится "что... а".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обычно выражение "как ни крути" обособляется. Но в Вашем примере мы видим стык подчинительного союза ЧТО и союзного слова КАК, а также  "а" как продолжение союза "что". По правилу на стыке союзов запятая в таком случае не ставится. Так что вы правы: "***Происходящее объясняется тем, что как ни крути, а основной контингент читателей журнала - женщины".***